# SrSecEng - how to optimize for future vision

Tags: cloud-computing, professional-education, programming, career

I'd like to do Cloud, Security, and Programming, ideally in Python/Golang. To move from process automation towards asynchronous, distributed, autonomic systems. Security inspired by DevOps/SRE practices. That's my ideal trajectory.

I've been doing mostly SOAR and related stuff within Security Operations - a little cloud, some scripting, sysadmin stuff, detection & response... that sort of thing.

How do I take myself from A to B, the hard way... Actually learning things not just resume-building? I am not deep into programming / CS so manageable learning curve is best.

Comment: Your question is "how do I actually learn things?" and that's a weird question. You... learn them... The best plan is to build things that work so that you can take a "portfolio" approach to showing what you can do. And as for future-proofing, the best plan is to "learn how to learn". That way, when something important emerges, then you can quickly pick that up. However, we can't devise a learning plan for you.

Comment: @schroeder thanks for the response.